# Teleport while Controlling GameObject in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a freshman design student and they've asked us to create a game on unity3D without much training on it so needless to say I don't know much except for the super basic stuff. I don't know anything about c# and I've been having an issue making a gameobject teleport. I've spent 6 hours searching for a solution online and the only conclusion I got to was that my object is probably having issues teleporting because of the way I am controlling it - something to do with the controller remembering the last position before the teleport and returning to it. I have no idea how to fix it though.
So this is what my scene looks like: I have a sphere as my character, I move it to this other object that has a collider as trigger which then teleports my sphere to a different point (black object) on the terrain. As soon as my object reaches there, it starts sliding back to the point where the teleport happened. I even tried edit > project settings > physics > auto sync transforms as many suggested that and it worked for them.

This is the code by which I control my player:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1;
    public float spacing = 1;
    private Vector3 pos;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        pos = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
            pos.x += spacing;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
            pos.x -= spacing;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
            pos.z -= spacing;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
            pos.z += spacing;


        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, pos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
```

and I also have a camera that follows the sphere using this code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CompleteCameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;       //Public variable to store a reference to the player game object


    private Vector3 offset;         //Private variable to store the offset distance between the player and camera

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        //Calculate and store the offset value by getting the distance between the player's position and camera's position.
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }
    
    // LateUpdate is called after Update each frame
    void LateUpdate () 
    {
        // Set the position of the camera's transform to be the same as the player's, but offset by the calculated offset distance.
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

and I have another code on the camera that makes me be able to look around using my mouse

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 public class FlyCamera : MonoBehaviour
 {
     /*
     Writen by Windexglow 11-13-10.  Use it, edit it, steal it I don't care.  
     Converted to C# 27-02-13 - no credit wanted.
     Simple flycam I made, since I couldn't find any others made public.  
     Made simple to use (drag and drop, done) for regular keyboard layout  
     wasd : basic movement
     shift : Makes camera accelerate
     space : Moves camera on X and Z axis only.  So camera doesn't gain any height*/
     float mainSpeed = 700.0f; //regular speed
     float shiftAdd = 950.0f; //multiplied by how long shift is held.  Basically running
     float maxShift = 2000.0f; //Maximum speed when holdin gshift
     float camSens = 0.25f; //How sensitive it with mouse
     private Vector3 lastMouse = new Vector3(255, 255, 255); //kind of in the middle of the screen, rather than at the top (play)
     private float totalRun = 1.0f;
     void Update()
     {
         lastMouse = Input.mousePosition - lastMouse;
         lastMouse = new Vector3(-lastMouse.y * camSens, lastMouse.x * camSens, 0);
         lastMouse = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x + lastMouse.x, transform.eulerAngles.y + lastMouse.y, 0);
         transform.eulerAngles = lastMouse;
         lastMouse = Input.mousePosition;
         //Mouse  camera angle done.  
         //Keyboard commands
         float f = 0.0f;
         Vector3 p = GetBaseInput();
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
         {
             totalRun += Time.deltaTime;
             p = p * totalRun * shiftAdd;
             p.x = Mathf.Clamp(p.x, -maxShift, maxShift);
             p.y = Mathf.Clamp(p.y, -maxShift, maxShift);
             p.z = Mathf.Clamp(p.z, -maxShift, maxShift);
         }
         else
         {
             totalRun = Mathf.Clamp(totalRun * 0.5f, 1f, 1000f);
             p = p * mainSpeed;
         }
         p = p * Time.deltaTime;
         Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
         { //If player wants to move on X and Z axis only
             transform.Translate(p);
             newPosition.x = transform.position.x;
             newPosition.z = transform.position.z;
             transform.position = newPosition;
         }
         else
         {
             transform.Translate(p);
         }
     }
     private Vector3 GetBaseInput()
     { //returns the basic values, if it's 0 than it's not active.
         Vector3 p_Velocity = new Vector3();
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
         {
             p_Velocity += new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
         {
             p_Velocity += new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
         {
             p_Velocity += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
         {
             p_Velocity += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
         }
         return p_Velocity;
     }
 }
```

Please let me know if there's a specific part of my code that I need to edit to resolve this or alternatively if you have a different code that won't give me this issue, that would make my life so much easier. If I need to edit something or you're sharing a code, please respond with the complete (corrected) code because otherwise I will just be even more confused.

I know this is a super long post and I am sorry but I am really desperate. It's been really hard studying online and basically having to teach myself all of this. This is for a final project so I will really appreciate any help you can throw my way. Thank you for reading and thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT: The teleport code is executing fine because I do teleport to the chosen location, I just end up sliding back to the point which I teleported from.

This is the teleporting code I am using.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ui;
    public GameObject objToTP;
    public Transform tpLoc;
    void Start()
    {
        ui.SetActive(false);
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        ui.SetActive(true);
        if ((other.gameObject.tag == "Player") && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            objToTP.transform.position = tpLoc.transform.position;
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerExit()
    {
        ui.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the main reason why your character is drifting back to original position is that the `pos` variable in the `MyPlayer` script stays the same after teleporting.

Remedy for that will be changing `pos` variable from `Teleport`  script after `objToTP.transform.position = tpLoc.transform.position;`. Something like `objToTP.gameobject.GetComponent<MyPlayer>().pos = tpLoc.transform.position`;

But make sure that `objToTP` has component `MyPlayer` and `pos` in `MyPlayer` is public.

Once again: it's a simple way to resolve your problem. In a real project you should create more flexible architecture, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you sliding back because you moving player with  `transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards` in Update(). 
And you moving it to coordinates that was got from your input